# From C++ to Actionscript via FLASCC

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, gesture-recognition, flascc

I'm hoping to get some feedback from anyone who is familiar with BOTH C++ AND Actionscript. I am not a C++ coder unfortunately.

I am developing Kinect applications using the AIRKinect framework. Unfortunately a limitation of this framework is the lack of any useful gesture dection algorithms.

I came across this gesture recognition library built in C++.
http://www.nickgillian.com/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=GRT.FAQ

There is also the Flash C+++ cross compiler(formerly known as Alchemy)
http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/flascc/

I was wondering if it might be possible to convert this gesture recognition library into  a swc(Flash format) so I can use it with AIRKinect?

Comment: It depends on whether this library uses system APIs, and which APIs it uses. Anyway, I think that it is better to use [Native Extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) feature of AIR and turn the library into a native extension. It will work regardless of APIs the library uses, and will be much more performant, because the code of the lib will be executed like any other normal native code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Possible.

> FlasCC uses a version of LLVM-GCC 4.2 with a custom LLVM backend that
>   generates ActionScript bytecode capable of running within the Flash
>   Runtime. More specifically, the bytecode runs in the ActionScript
>   virtual machine (AVM). This lets you compile arbitrary C/C++ code into
>   a managed bytecode format capable of high performance execution within
>   the Flash Runtime on Mac, Windows, or Linux

more information read a FlasCC doucmentation: [FlasCC](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/flascc/README.html)

If you want download FlasCC. rejoin this site(Adobe rebrand): https://creative.adobe.com/apps?trial=GAME&promoid=KBYQD

and click Download.[image]

redirect to this site. download Flascc tools.
[image]

Comment: thanks! So it's possible, but is it practical? Will have to research how much work it would take. Also, still need to figure out the pros and cons of the Native Extension vs FLASCC route.

Comment: FlasCC perfomance awesome. I tested. So Advanced Flash Game Developers Using C, C ++, the calculated height of the code required to work. In fact, At first ANE aim using a iphone, Android Native Class ex) IAP, GameCenter. ANE is almost Wrappers Concept.